# Is there any STANDARD U.S.-compatible keyboard layout for typing extended Latin?

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard-layout, standards

I am getting REALLY tired of adjusting my typing habit when needing to type characters such as `ø`, `å` and `æ` to name a few, after switching from Mac OSX to Windows to Mac OSX, which I unfortunately have to. Haven't tried Linux recently, but it could prove to have its own layout again.

Is there any standard layout one can expect? To type `ø` for instance, I need to hold down Alt key and hit the O key on Mac. Simple enough. On Windows however, that would be Alt and L.

Is there any standard layout for my usage pattern? I am typing mostly Norwegian, but occasionally also Swedish letters.

If I knew there was a standard, I could just install the layout on the platforms I use and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the encodings, which should be standard instead of relying on the keyboards mappings.

Ø on Windows and Mac should map to [Alt + 0216](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d8/index.htm)

```
Encodings
HTML Entity (decimal)   &#216;
HTML Entity (hex)   &#xd8;
HTML Entity (named) &Oslash;
How to type in Microsoft Windows    Alt +00D8
Alt 0216
UTF-8 (hex) 0xC3 0x98 (c398)
UTF-8 (binary)  11000011:10011000
UTF-16 (hex)    0x00D8 (00d8)
UTF-16 (decimal)    216
UTF-32 (hex)    0x000000D8 (00d8)
UTF-32 (decimal)    216
C/C++/Java source code  "\u00D8"
Python source code  u"\u00D8"
```

Comment: OS X doesn't support alt codes by default. You can use them by switching to the Unicode Hex Input keyboard layout, but there is only a version of it based on the U.S. layout available and it [breaks some key combinations like option-left and option-delete](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/41657/3936).